# Comments *after* an answer helped more than the answer

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982377/using-nessos-stream-to-reduce-the-time-to-get-and-write-query-output-to-a-csv) recently on SO.  A user provided an answer that *was not* a direct solution but that user **did** provide useful input--through the comments--that eventually resolved my question.

How should situations like this be handled?  Should I accept the user's answer or just let it stay "unaccepted?"  Other questions here on SOMeta imply that unless the answer was not a direct resolution of the question, there should be no "right" answer, but it seems like if a user helps tremendously in the comments to their own answer, there should be some "reward" for that user.

Comment: Edit the comments into the answer.

Comment: Or ask the poster to do so. They are usually happy to oblige.

Answer (score 3):

As [ryanyuyu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu) stated in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336151/comments-after-an-answer-helped-more-than-the-answer#comment403648_336151) the correct solution is to ask the answerer to update the answer with the information in the comments. If they don't seem willing to do that, then do it yourself. Adding this information to the answer will make it a better answer and of more use to future visitors.

Comments are, as we keep saying, 2<sup>nd</sup> class citizens and are subject to removal at a moment's notice. If there is important information in a comment make sure it goes into a more permanent place like an answer or question.

Answer (score 0):

Accept means only one thing - "this post helped OP the most" so you are free to accept it or not.

If you believe Q/A pair is generally useful - consider either editing comments in (directly or preferably asking poster to do so). Alternatively you can construct complete answer and refer to existing as inspiration (marking as "wiki" if you feel most content is not provided by you).

If you feel question would not get much attention in the future - keeping long comments is fine.